# Box plot showing mean as a line

Tags: r, mean, boxplot

Is it possible to create a boxplot that shows both mean and median as a line with the standard boxplot function of R ? My current solution displays the mean as a cross:

```
set.seed(1234)
values <- runif(10,0,1)
boxplot(values)
points(mean(values),col="red",pch=4,lwd = 4)
```

[image: Image of boxplot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, you could also overplot:

```
set.seed(753)
df <- data.frame(y=rt(100, 4), x=gl(5, 20))
bx.p <- boxplot(y~x, df)
bx.p$stats[3, ] <- unclass(with(df, by(y, x, FUN = mean)))
bxp(bx.p, add=T, boxfill="transparent", medcol="red", axes=F, outpch = NA, outlty="blank", boxlty="blank", whisklty="blank", staplelty="blank")
```

Explanation via @scs:

`bxp$stats` returns a matrix that contains the lower whisker, the lower hinge, the median, the upper hinge and the extreme of the upper whisker for each boxplot. The solution above overwrites the median specified in `bx.p$stats[3, ]` with the mean value. The `bxp` function is a function to plot boxplot objects.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I like to have some indication other than just color that would distinguish two things on the same plot. Imagine that for some obscure reason I wanted to read this on actual paper and the only printer on which I can print it has only black ink.

Comment: Put in a legend: `legend('topleft', lty=c(1, 1), lwd=rep(3, 2), col=c("black", "red"), legend = c("median", "mean"), horiz = TRUE, bg="transparent")`.

Comment: My printer uses black ink for the legend, too. :-)

Comment: Making one line slightly shorter or longer than the other would be a sufficient additional visual cue, I think.

Comment: You can make ot a dotted or dashed line (e.g. by adding `medlty="dotted"`) - this will even save you some ink. ;->

Comment: Yes, that works. The person who buys my ink thanks you.

Answer (score 11):

The default plotting of `boxplot` makes the width of the box go from `0.8` to `1.2` in the `x-axis`.

You can hence draw a line for the mean with the below code:

```
lines(c(0.8, 1.2), rep(mean(values), 2), col="red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the actual problem, but it is not easily scalable to solutions with multiple boxplots in the same window or plots with custom width / height. Therefore, the more generic solution below was selected as accepted answer.