# box plot with whiskers with mean value line

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to create box plot with whiskers with mean value line as below.[Mean cashflows of two different model (166 values) comparing with true distribution mean(1 value)]

How to create like this in r?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide your current code and graph

Comment: `boxplot(y ~ x, data=your_dataframe_name)` will get you started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Box plot showing mean as a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689329/box-plot-showing-mean-as-a-line)

Comment: boxplot(mean.DCL,mean.ODP,mean.Mack,mean.res,col =(c("gold","green","blue","yellow")),main="Histogram of Mean Reserves",xlab= "Reserves",names=c("DCL","ODP","Mack","True"))
  boxplot(sd.DCL.Procerr,sd.ODP.Procerr,sd.Mack.Procerr,sd.res,col =(c("gold","green","blue","yellow")),main= "Histogram of SD Reserves",xlab= "Reserves",names=c("DCL","ODP","Mack","True"))
  where mean.DCL,mean.ODP,mean.Mack are [1,200] and mean.res is [1].

Comment: Hi ANG, this is not duplicate. I want the line of True mean to run from zero of x-axis till the end of the axis, passing through all the box plots in the graph. Also there is not general solution provided in the link you mentioned under duplicate. Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

the below lines solved my problem:
boxplot(mean.DCL,mean.ODP,mean.Mack,col =(c("gold","green","blue")),main="Histogram of Process Mean Reserves",xlab= "Reserves",names=c("DCL","ODP","Mack"),ylim = c(2200000, 3500000),by = 2000000)
  lines(x = c(0:S), y = rep(mean.res,S+1), col="red",lty = 2, lwd = 2)

[the mean is the dotted line through the other values of all models considered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzlCM.png)